# Para que sirve realmente .indexOn en firebase

Tags: firebase

Desde hace tiempo que llevo usando `firebase` sin embargo no me queda claro el propósito de la regla `.indexOn`. Esto agiliza las búsquedas en los datos secundarios o algo así ¿?.

por ejemplo:

si tengo una base de datos con la siguiente estructura:

```
Plantas
    silvestres
        nombre:flor1
        cantidad:10
    hogares
        nombre:flor2
        cantidad:20
    jardines:
        nombre:flor3
        cantidad:30
```

y en las reglas defino:

```
"rules":{
"Plantas":{
  "indexOn"["nombre","cantidad"]
 }
```

esto acelerara la consulta de los campos definidos en el `.indexOn`

Comment: Definitivamente ayuda al rendimiento de las consultas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase permite realizar consultas de datos usando una
clave secundaria arbitraria. Si sabes con antelación cuáles serán tus
 índices, puedes definirlos a través de la regla **.indexOn**

Revisa el ejemplo de la documentación:

---

La manera más sencilla de explicar esto es a través de un ejemplo. Aquí en `Firebase` somos amantes de los dinosaurios. A continuación, incluiremos un fragmento una base de datos de muestra con información sobre dinosaurios. La utilizaremos para explicar cómo funciona `.indexOn` con `orderByChild()`.

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

Imaginemos que, en nuestra app, a menudo debemos ordenar los dinosaurios por nombre, altura y longitud, pero nunca por peso. Para mejorar el rendimiento de nuestras consultas, podemos darle esa información a `Firebase`.

Debido a que los nombres de los dinosaurios son solo las claves, `Firebase` optimiza con antelación las consultas por nombre del dinosaurio, dado que esta es la clave del registro. Podemos usar `.indexOn` para indicarle a `Firebase` que también optimice las consultas por altura y longitud.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
      ".indexOn": ["height", "length"]
    }
  }
}
```

Al igual que otras reglas, puedes especificar una regla de `.indexOn` en cualquier nivel de tus reglas. En el ejemplo anterior, la ubicamos en el nivel de raíz, ya que todos los datos de dinosaurios se almacenan en la raíz de la base de datos.

Comment: entonces resumiendo si optimiza la consulta

Comment: @Revsky01 revisa este benchmarking: https://medium.com/@jasonbyrne/benchmarking-firebase-indexon-565182c723de realizado por  Jason Byrne